# Toggle "more/less" text and show only clicked element

Tags: javascript, click

I'm trying to select only the clicked element, but it doesn't work. How can I toggle class and text for the clicked element?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30cr1298/). What should I change from the following code?

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
 $('.data').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open');
  }
});
   $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'less' ? 'more' : 'less');
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.data {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.data.open {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

   <div class="post">
      <div class="data">
        <div>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</div>
      </div>
   <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
   </div>

   <div class="post">
      <div class="data">
        <div>bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</div>
      </div>
   <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/30cr1298/16/

Comment: hi @ZakariaAcharki, this work for me. thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll post an answer for the future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the `each()` loop :

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.data').removeClass('open');
  $('.click').text('more');

  var data = $(this).prev('.data');

  if ($(this).text() === 'less') {
    $(this).text('more')
    data.removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $(this).text('less')
    data.addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.data {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.data.open {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="data">
      <div>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</div>
    </div>
    <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="data">
      <div>bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</div>
    </div>
    <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the following code  
`if ($(this).text() === 'less') {
    $(this).text('more')
    data.removeClass('open');
  }`
doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

So, since we have multiple div with class `data` we are getting both of them toggled.

To solve this. After the click happens, we select the button on which the click happened using `$(this)`, then get the correct div with class `data` using the jquery method [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and execute the same logic!

```js
$('.click').click(function() {

   $(this).prev('.data').each(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    } else {

      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
   $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'less' ? 'more' : 'less');
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.data {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.data.open {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

   <div class="post">
      <div class="data">
        <div>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</div>
      </div>
   <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
   </div>

   <div class="post">
      <div class="data">
        <div>bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</div>
      </div>
   <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) with [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$('.click').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).text(this.textContent == 'less' ? 'more' : 'less');
});
```

```css
.container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.data {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.data.open {
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="data">
            <div>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</div>
        </div>
        <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="data">
            <div>bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</div>
        </div>
        <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with different class names

jQuery

$('.click').click(function() {

```
$("div[class^='data']").each(function() {

 if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
     $(this).removeClass('open');
 } else {

   $(this).removeClass('open');
   $(this).addClass('open');
 }
});
   $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'less' ? 'more' : 'less');
});
```

CSS

```
  .container {
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
   }

  .container a {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px;
    }

  .data1, .data2 {
      background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
       height: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

  .open {
     height: auto;
    }
```

HTML

```
   <div class="container">

      <div class="post">
          <div class="data1">
            <div>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</div>
         </div>
      <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
       </div>

       <div class="post">
          <div class="data2">
            <div>bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</div>
          </div>
        <a class="click" href="javascript:void(0);">more</a> 
       </div>

    </div>
```